# How to decode DSProxy input data

Tags: solidity, abi, delegatecall, decoding, dsproxy

I'm trying to debug a tx made through a DSProxy deployed on Polygonscan, but I'm having a difficult time since the `_data` part of the DSProxy function input is ABI-encoded. I would have to comb through the function selectors in `_target`, and then decode the rest of `_data` using the ABI of that specific function being called. I'm trying to find the most time-efficient way to decode `_data`, either via an online tool or via ethers.js.

Here is what the input data looks like:

[image]

tx link: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x1566384b58fdd7120e0908e887532354500db3fa0135fdea7ab3e62f18cbad6b

Comment: There's no easy way, unfortunately. I have been [trying](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1346396518450950146) to get Etherscan to do this for a long time now!